# How to change/prioritize function execution in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, mxml

So basically I have a component with my event dispatched:

```
<components:MyComp id="Id" myDispatchedEvent(event)/>
```

In script tags I have that function:

```
private function myDispatchedEvent(event:Event):void  
{  
  //Here I have my static function with title and handler function showConfirmation 
      Calculate.showConfirmation("String Title", function(event:Close):void  
      {  
          if(bla bla bla)  
          //lots of code etc. ...  
      });  
//myDispatchEvent function continues here..  
}
```

So problem is with my static function's showConfirmation handler, if I go through debug, it just skips that function and continues doing myDispatchedEvent. Why doesn't anonymous function inside showConfirmation function execute?
Thanks

Comment: Could you show the code where the anonymous function is called? Can't tell from this code alone why it's not executing.

Comment: Calculate.showConfirmation("String Title", function(event:Close):void  
      {  
          if(bla bla bla)  
          //lots of code etc. ...  
      });  that is where it gets executed. I could write separate function easily like: Calculate.showConfirmation("String Title", myNewSeparateFunction), it doesn't matter, it still won't get called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are executing upon call. In your case you have just declaration of it. Call this function somewhere inside `Calculate.showConfirmation` and it will be executed.

Something like the following:

```
public class Calculate
{
    public static function showConfirmation(title:String, func:Function):void
    {
        // The call I'm talking about is here
        func(new Close());
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean like: Calculate.showConfirmation("String Title", myNewSeparateFunction) and then somewhere: private function myNewSeparateFunction(event:Close):void{ //code} ?

Comment: I am not sure I quite understand your proposal. Calculate class has that showConfirmation function which calls another static function showConfirmationImpl. I still don't understand why it isn't getting called. It should be like this myDispatchedEvent(start)->showConfirmation->showConfirmationImpl->anonymous function->myDispatchedEvent(end). But at the moment it's like this: myDispatchedEvent(start)->myDispatchedEvent(end)->showConfirmation->showConfirmationImpl->anonymous function.

Comment: I think it is better to place Calculate's listing in your question.

Comment: Well anyway I fixed my issue, though that function still executes later, but I found another workaround, it's hard to explain it. Thanks for help guys. I'll mark your answer as solved.

Answer (score 1):

Let me say first that what you're trying to do is quite strange. I'd try to code a different solution, but this depends on what you're trying to do. It you tell us a more about it we could find a better way to reach your goal. BTW, you can do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               minHeight="600" minWidth="955">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.CloseEvent;

            public static function myFunction(param:String, func:Function):void {
                trace("executing");
                func.apply();
            }

            protected function labelx_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
                trace("click");
                Tests.myFunction("Test", function():void {
                    if (event.localX > 0) {
                        trace("Test");
                    }
                    else {
                        trace("No");
                    }
                });

            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Button id="labelx"
              label="Click me"
              click="labelx_clickHandler(event)"/>
</s:Application>
```

Something similar what Constantiner has already told you. If you don't execute the function that you're passing to your static function as a parameter inside this static function, it won't be executed.